# Leave approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow

There are two people to approve a leave, first manager then senior manager. If the manager is on leave then the task should be sent to the senior manager.

How can I implement this using SharePoint designer?

Comment: If you have your leave list on SharePoint, which I assume you do, you could have the workflow check to see if either of the approvers are on leave.  You can also set the workflow to run in serial or parallel so there is not issue:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579

Comment: Have a look at this http://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-an-approval-workflow-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a `Delegation` process! and to achieve that I suggest to

- create a approvers list that has 3 columns

  - an approver email column.
  - a delegate email column.
  - a status column to show availability as yes or no.
- In you workflow check based on the status column if the user is available or not, and based on each approver status you will forward the request to the delegate who in this case is the senior manager.

Answer (score 0):

Watch SharePoint 2013 Leave Requests Workflow video. it's very helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdscRGHMWqQ

Comment: not helpful, some other suggestions please.